# How to use join query in iOS using parse framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ios7, parse-platform

I have two tables:

**1.)**   `User:name,age,address-id`

**2.)**   `Address: address-id,street-name,city,state`

How can I get the list of users with address using JOIN query?

like

```
SELECT User.name, User.age, Address.street-name, Address.city, Address.state FROM User INNER JOIN Address ON:User.address-id=Address.address-id;
```

How can I get data from this two tables in one query?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS

Comment: Do you have any code for this as i couldn't implement using above link as it doesn't work.

Comment: Facing same problem..! any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a JOIN query directly, as the database backing parse.com is not a SQL database but a NoSQL database.

In your particular case, all you need to do is include the address in the user query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];  // Or [PFUser query] if users are PFUsers
[query whereKey:@"someKey" equalTo:@"someValue"]; // Whatever you need to get a correct list of users
[query includeKey:@"address-id"];  // This includes all related Address objects in the result set
[query findObjects];  // Or preferably findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
```

This assumes that your address-id property is a relation or pointer.

Comment: in above code where can i enter the Address table name? So, how will parse know that data will fetched from "Address" table.

Comment: Don't you have a relation between the user and the address? When you add the address-id column in parse, make sure it is a POINTER column, pointing to the Address class.